# Capture helper without html buffer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang

I have a view helper that wraps a block call in a `catch` statement to ensure some `throw` gets handeled properly:

```
def if_reachable(&block)
  catch(:unreachable) do
    capture(&block)
  end
end
```

I can use the helper in my slim views like this

```
- if_reachable do
  | I won't be printed cause something is not reachable
  - throw(:unreachable)
```

The important part is that in my view I don't see the text `I won't be printed...`. That's the reason for the use of Rails' `capture` helper.

The problem is, that I also want to use the same helper in inline ruby as well:

```
/ this is also inside a slim template
- data = if_reachable { my_service.load_data }
```

and if no `:unreachable` is thrown I want to have the return value of `my_service.load_data`.

> The problem is: When no template is involved, the `capture` helper always returns `nil` and throws away the return value of `my_service.load_data`

Some ways I already considered would be

**Writing a seperate helper function:** That would be confusing to know which helper when to use.

**Wrapping inline template ruby code into their own helper methods and use `return`:** Would be confusing if a developer tries to use the helper and it can't be used without a seperate helper method

```
def my_helper
  if_reachable do
    return my_service.load_data
  end
end
```

Any idea how to solve this? Is it possible to check if a block comes from a template or is pure ruby?

Comment: Just an idea: maybe you can check who the caller is using for example `caller[5]` inside the helper.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think that would be hard to do, because IMHO you can only figure out if it is a .rb oder .slim file, but inside a slim file you could also have pure ruby.

Comment: It seems to me that you are using exceptions for flow control and much logic in your views/helpers. Perhaps you should consider using the presenter pattern?

Comment: `throw` and `catch` are specifically designed for flow control, and they are different than traditional exception (e.g. the performance is much better when using `throw` than `raise`). Avdi Grimm has a good blog post about it http://rubylearning.com/blog/2011/07/12/throw-catch-raise-rescue--im-so-confused/ I'm working with legacy code, and introducing a presenter pattern would lead to a lot of refactoring, which can't be done with the amount of time I have for this.